# LTS of this simple FSP

Tags: automata, finite-automata, process-algebras

I have this finite-state process with the corresponding labeled transition system:

[image]

The FSP is:

```
MAKER = (kochen -> fertig -> MAKER).
USER = (fertig -> essen -> USER). 

||MAKER_USER = (USER||MAKER).
```

Why is `essen` possible after the second `kochen`? `USER` needs to have `fertig` in order to able to `essen` right?

Comment: What do "LTS" and "FSP" stand for?

Comment: lts = labelled transition states, 
fsp = finite state process.. anyway, i got now the answer..

Comment: @doniyor Would you mind sharing the answer with us (if you think it will be interesting to others)? Or, alternatively, you can delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

The middle transition `fertig` is the shared action so this must be ran parallel, but after this there are 2 transitions which dont have to run parallel, one is `kochen` and the other is `essen`.

Assume, we are now in the point where `fertig` is done by both processes and now we have 2 options, `kochen` and `essen`. We do both one after another as options: if i do `kochen` then the option `essen` is left, if i do `essen`, then `kochen` is left. I also have to do what is left to do.

So, let's say, I choose `essen` then go to `USER` back, but if I do `kochen` first, then I have to do `essen` which is the second `essen` in this case.

Comment: hope that i understood right. :)).